# Who plays Chilblains in ‘Ice Spy’ and ‘The Duo Defy’ in the Adam West Batman TV show?

Tags: dc, batman, batman-1966

Who is the actor that plays Chilblains in the episodes Ice Spy and The Duo Defy from the Batman TV show from season 2 in 1967 when Eli Wallach played Mr. Freeze?  IMDB says it is Al Waytt Sr, but I know that is wrong.

Comment: why is it wrong?

Comment: @NKCambell Maybe they know Al Waytt personally

Comment: maybe - and I'm aware that sometimes IMDB can be incorrect - but some detail as to why we should accept one premise vs another, I would find helpful @DCOPTimDowd :)

Comment: Actually, the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519481/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) lists Mr. Waytt only as "henchman", so I don't even know who this *Chilblains* is without seeing the episodes in question. Although, the picture on display does ring a bell. I think I saw something involving him in a Cinemassacre video.

Comment: I had to look up the script for "Ice Spy" to determine the same @DCOPTimDowd - Chilblains appears to be a non-speaking henchman in that episode that is twice given a command by Mr. Freeze.

Comment: What I meant, @NKCampbell, is that I can't tell which of the two men in the [picture](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0943511/mediaviewer/rm803601152) is Chilblains without seeing the show, as there's nothing identifying which one is which. So I would be incapable of cross-referencing a likeness to answer the question. I can see your confusion with my wording though.

Comment: I sent in an edit to IMDB.  That is why the site no longer says that Al Wyatt Sr. played Chilblains.  Wyatt played bad guys in westerns and appeared in other episodes of Batman so I know what Wyatt looks like.  He played a henchman in the fight sequences, but he was not Chilblains.  The actor that played Chilblains may have had only one line of dialogue, but he did get a lot of face time in the episodes.

Comment: The picture you are referencing is from the Joker is Wild/Batman Is Riled (Wrong episodes).  Wyatt is the one on the left with his hand on the newspaper.

Comment: Chilblains is on the far right in the picture.  https://i2.wp.com/www.tor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Batman-IceSpy03.jpg?resize=630%2C473&type=vertical